# How to check an attribute is empty everywhere or not in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this

```
    <siddata lastUpdated="18.09.2013 06:47 ">
  <data itemnumber="12" variant1="Lys eg" variant2="" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="lys" var2code="" ></data>
  <data itemnumber="124" variant1="Røget eg" variant2="" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="rog" var2code="" ></data>
</siddata>
```

As you can see in the XML `variant2` is null for both rows.I want to check this in an if case .Tried something like this

```
  <xsl:if test="siddata/data[@variant2] !=''">

                  </xsl:if>
```

but never worked.
**Note:I want to check weather both rows are empty or not.**

Comment: 1) When you say "null", you seem to mean that the attribute exists but its value is an empty string. By "empty" do you mean the same thing? Or do you include the attribute not existing? 2) When you say something doesn't work, please specify the specific result you received and how it contrasted with what you expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be true if any of the values is nonempty, false otherwise:

```
siddata/data/@variant2 != ''
```

This will be true if all of the values are empty, false otherwise:

```
not(siddata/data/@variant2 != '')
```